# testing flash movies performance agaisnt range or computers and browsers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am half way done with making my first flash web game. I put alot of work into it and dont really know how great the performance will be on browsers and range of different types of computers. This is my first time working with flash in general. I was wondering if there is any tools to test my game out against browsers and hardware. The game might work great on my computer, but how can i ever tell how great it works in a range of browsers and computers.

Doesnt have to be tools but techniques or anything.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the VMWarePlayer from VMWare, they have a number of (free) images you can download from various operating systems although MacOS and Windows are not among them. For that you may just have to have some limited beta test.

Comment: is testing for performance in a virtualized environment really a worthwhile endeavor?

Comment: @grapefrukt: yes and no ... of course you will not get the same performance, but you can make a comparison ... a friend of mine is on linux, and had better results for a flash player running in a virtualized windows ... it is not really the perfect way of measuring, but it'll give you some pointers ...

Answer (score 0):

One tool that you might want to take a look at is CPUKiller3 http://www.cpukiller.com/. Basically allows you to slow down your processor. This way you can test your swf on a slower machine. (I have not used this software myself however).

You may also like to set up a few virtual machines (VMware, Virtual PC etc) and set each one up differently with different OS. It might be a bit of overkill though.

Also with Firefox you can get pluggins which will allow you to switch between Flash versions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You also might wanna take a look at http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test a FLASH game on a huge user base . you can host it on
[kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com) 
and a low-fi version with drummed down art work on [newgrounds](http://www.newgrounds.com) its here you get the maximum possible play tests for your game on an extremely diverse user base with different browsers and  pc's

Comment: yea, I was planning on putting it on both of those sites